# LR: Can I make the pseudorandom in LoadRunner deterministic?

Tags: random, load-testing, deterministic, loadrunner

There are a couple of sources for random in LoadRunner scenarios:

- `rand` () function
- Random think time deltas (runtime settings)
- Random pacing time components (runtime settings)
- Random parameters (as part of the VUGen test)

I use those functionalities, and I could live with their pseudorandomness.
I cannot, however, live with the fact that all scenario runs containing at least one of those functionalities behave pseudorandomly AND indeterministic, i.e. for a given start state (random seed), I want two runs to generate EXACTLY the same load, including timing (pacing and think times). 
So I want two runs to be based on EXACTLY the same random sequences. 
That means that I want to seed all random generators myself, as part of the initialization of each run.

I can use `srand` () to set a seed value for `rand` (). Setting a specific (hard-coded) seed value upon init always results in the same sequence delivered by `rand` () -- for all virtual users. If I seed with the VUser ID number, I would even get different `rand` () sequences for every vuser, while they still are the same from run to run for each user.

**What about the other pseudorandom sources in LR, those beyond `rand` ()? 
Do I have a chance to seed them all so I get deterministic scenario behavior?**

I think that would greatly help.

Without a mechanism like that, one has to plan for very long, and/or very high-traffic test scenarios in order to "average out" the randomness in the results statistics (do you agree with this?) which I do all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already covered.   I have been working with LoadRunner since 4.51 and I cannot recall a version without the ability to set a random seed.   Typically this is in the scenario run time settings set in the controller.    You should be able to find documentation on this for your version of LoadRunner by opening the Acrobat version of the Controller User's guide and searching fror the term "seed."

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Because it's true. How could I overlook this. It is where it is supposed to be, yet I did not know about it. On next occasion, I'll verify that this really works, but I think that was exactly the pointer I was look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seeding the random number generator is imperative for a system like load runner.  Perfect example - I have a code change I want to test.  I seed the random number generator and then run with and without the changed code.  The sequence of functions executed will be random, but both tests will use the same sequence.  This allows me to see the exact impact of my code change.  Without the ability to see the random number generator, I would have to run very long tests under very high load to try to average out the randomness.

Without the seed, the 2nd test would choose a completely different path.  And on another iteration, yet another completely different path.  I want RANDOM sequences, but REPEATABLE RANDOM sequences.  This is why all modern languages allow you to seed a random number generator.  The Load Runner client just needs to add a single text field that allows you to enter the "seed value" for their random number generator.

Comment: I totally agree. So how do you seed the random generators that VUgen feed VUGen scripts? Especially the random-based parameters? Question is not "if", but "how".

Comment: I now have a hard time accepting either the "NO" answer from K.Sandell and the "YES. IMPERATIVE" answer from John. Both are right -- NO because it cannot be done, and YES because it would be required to get stable, comparable results without generating load for a long time (so random "averages" out).

Comment: I must add that even if you'd achieve an exact RND sequence there are other things that are different on the Controller/LoadGen that makes the run different anyway. lr_think_time() uses (if set) random X% to Y% and this random time is something you have no control over, and seeding that is as far as I know impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: **NO**.

```
Random implies just what it says => "Random".
```

If you use the "built in" random features of parameters you are pretty much screwed as you have no control over how the internal random-seeds are initialized, and this can not predict in any way the next value.

If what you ultimately want to achieve is to extrapolate the results and predict server behavior under load you are in for a very rocky road.

**Extrapolating results**

```
Your run with 100 vusers and achieve an avg. of 50-60 hits/sec with
response times under 3 sec.

Logically 1000 vusers (10x load) would give you 500-600 hits/sec ... 

But what about the response times? How do you extrapolate them? How do you know
when the web-server(s) chokes and achieves it's knee-point?
```

Remember that the hits/sec is directly proportional to the response times... so predicting hits/sec (or pages/sec) becomes very difficult and inaccurate

**Things you can not control**

Even if you'd achieve an "exact" copy of another run you still have to deal with the response times and network delays, that in effect are always different, regardless of circumstances (and also totally out of your control).

**A more "realistic" way to define load**

Load-testing in itself is not an exact science, and no load-test can ever simulate the real world completely, but we can get close. The way we do it here is that we try to simulate the individual users as close as possible. This way we can set the load expectations according to user-types, something that the "business" people usually have a clue about.

We also divide the "users" into types, such as power, normal or novice user - the difference for these are the speed at which they operate (and the way they use the UI's).

By doing this we can "load" the target application with a certain "expected user load" instead of pages/sec or hits/sec values or other technical meters.

We also execute longer runs to see how the service behaves over time, so a 72h or more test is not unusual for the Endurance test phase. This also shows if there are any memory leaks over time on the servers and how background processes impact the server performance during "night time"

Comment: I see, and agree on the "72h or more test is not unusual for the Endurance test phase" statement, which is where I'm coming from. 

I strongly disagree, however, to "Random implies just what it says => 'Random'. " since we're talking about pseudo-random generators which are 100% deterministic and thus reproduceable if you have control over the seed values -- and still pseudo-random if you don't. 

So if I *do* have access to all seeds, I don't see the point why I should not make a certain load test run more reproduceable by generating exactly the same load -- depending on the test goal.

Comment: The situation at hand is that the randomly chosen test cases lead to very, very different data sets (in terms of complexity) to be processed, and I do not have a cheap or reliable way to categorize my test case data set in order to select only the complex, or only the cheap test cases. 

So selecting anything randomly (and not controlling *all* seeds) forces me to execute very, very long load test runs so the huge differences between the test cases "average out" and the run returns useful results.

Comment: "This way we can set the load expectations according to user-types, something that the "business" people usually have a clue about." -- yeah, *usually* ;)

Comment: I now have a hard time accepting either the "NO" answer from K.Sandell and the "YES. IMPERATIVE" answer from John. Both are right -- NO because it cannot be done, and YES because it would be required to get stable, comparable results without generating load for a long time (so random "averages" out).